# Embeded VCL Form with FMX Form

Tags: merge, firemonkey, vcl

I want to use `TWindowsMediaPlayer` in an FMX Form. I create it with this code, but playing media causes an error:

> Access violation at address 004080D6 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000500

How can resolve it?

```
var
  frmvlc: TFrmVlc;
begin
  frmvlc := TFrmVlc.Create(self);
  frmvlc.WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := filename; // it play video but not show it.
  self.AddObject(TFmxObject(frmvlc.Panel1));    error hier  

end;
```

Comment: VCL and FMX are simply not designed to be used together. For instance, if `frmvlc.Panel1` is a VCL `TPanel` then you can't type-cast it to `TFmxObject` and give it to `AddObject()`, because it does not derive from `TFmxObject` to begin with, so attempts to access `TFmxObject`'s functionality will fail. I have seen 3rd party solutions for using FMX inside a VCL project, but never the other way around.

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau